# Cannot send push notification via Azure Mobile Service

Tags: android, node.js, azure, cloud

I have setup a Mobile Service in Azure and connected it to my Android app. Through this app I am calling the Azure API to insert an object into a database table linked to the mobile service.

I have written the script that is executed before it gets inserted. That script is intended to send a push notification to another device.

Now the case is, the object gets inserted into table but no push notification is received. What could be wrong? How can i debug?

Here's my insert script:

```
function insert(item, user, request) {

    var devices = tables.getTable('Devices');

    var receiverHandle;

    devices.where({userId: item.receiver}).read({
        success: populateHandle
    });

    request.execute({
        success: function() {
            // Write to the response and then send the notification in the background
            request.respond();
            console.log(item);
            push.gcm.send(item.handle, item, {
                success: function(response) {
                    console.log('Push notification sent: ', response);
                }, error: function(error) {
                    console.log('Error sending push notification: ', error);
                }
            });
        }
    });

    function populateHandle(results){
       receiverHandle =  results[0].handle;
    }

}
```

Although logs state successful delivery of push notification. I am not receiving it on my device.

Here is one of the logs:

Push notification sent: { isSuccessful: true, statusCode: 201, body: '', headers: { 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'content-type': 'application/xml; charset=utf-8', server: 'Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0', date: 'Sun, 10 Aug 2014 15:01:52 GMT' }, md5: undefined }

Comment: I am assuming that you configured up all the GCM components on Azure and at Google that are required to deliver the messages to the device?  Do you see any errors in the console when this code executes?

Comment: Yes ofcourse i have configured the GCM. Which console i may see errors?

Comment: Click on the "LOGS" tab in your mobile service in the Azure Management Portal and you'll find entries there.

Comment: No logs there! Does it mean server was able to send push without issues?

Comment: I'd drop in more console.log statements earlier in your code stack to find out where the code is getting to. You don't have any error block for your request.execute statement. You also need to review your code as I'm not sure it is going to work as you expect it to.

Comment: Now its saying:
Error sending push notification: { [Error: 400 - The supplied notification payload is invalid.TrackingId:917415af-d506-4331-a86c-d8ed2d4d0303_G0,TimeStamp:8/5/2014 6:21:43 AM] code: '400', detail: 'The supplied notification payload is invalid.TrackingId:917415af-d506-4331-a86c-d8ed2d4d0303_G0,TimeStamp:8/5/2014 6:21:43 AM', statusCode: 400 }

Comment: The error message is telling you what you need to know.  You're trying to send something that isn't valid.  Why that is I can't say... I'd log the message content you are trying to send.  Developer documentation for GCM is here: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

Comment: Did you solve this? I am currently experiencing the same. I get a successful sent push msg. Whenever i call the gcm from my local machine it works just fine, but if using azure, it doesn't do anything than (supposingly) send to gcm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to [Migrate a Mobile Service to use Notification Hubs.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn635173.aspx)

Microsoft had been upgraded the Mobile Service, to push notifications powered by Notification Hubs. You will not be affected if you created the mobile service before the upgrade.

Base on the response { isSuccessful: true, statusCode: 201, body ... }, it indicate that your Mobile Service is the new version.

If you prefer to send push **without** Notification Hubs, **don't** use push.gcm.send, use the following code snippet instead.

```js
var legacyGcm = require('dpush');
legacyGcm.send(your_GCM_APIKEY, regId, item, function (error, response) {
    if (!error) {
        // success code
    } else {
        // error handling
    }
});
```

Comment: When using notification hubs, can push be sent to a tag only? I want to send push to a particular only. How can i achieve this?